# Modular LaTeX Documents: Multiple documents with book class using subfiles?

Tags: scrbook, subfiles

## Context

I currently have a single document with the class `srcbook`. I have partitioned it into various subfiles for easier handling. This document is fine by itself.... however, I want to include the entire document (title page, TOC, etc) in *another* document as a self contained section.

If that doesn't make sense, consider how *LaTeX* has various commands for structuring your document: `chapter`, `section`, `subsection`, `subsubsection`, etc, etc. That document then has a table of contents based on that structure.  However, it is sometimes beneficial to have / remind people what is in the current structure. Along those lines the package `minitoc` allows one to have a TOC for their chapters.

Using `subfiles` one can build up their document from various small documents containing these structured elements.

What I would like to do is essentially equivalent to making `book` its own structure element.  Thus one would end up with a meta document containing several books, each with their own title page, TOC, chapters, etc.

Thus one would have a title page for the document made of books as well.

One might ask, "why not simple take each element and demote it in the structure hierarchy? e.g. book --> chapter, chapter --> section, etc. Well, then I would need a TOC for sections, sections would need a chapter-esque header formatting, etc. Whereas the problem I am asking, is simply leaving the current structure in take, but allowing them to be pooled together as if there is a higher structure? e.g.

-meta-document

---book 1

-----chapter 1

-------section 1

---------subsection 1

-------section 2

---------subsection 1

---------subsection 2

---book 2

-----chapter 1

-------section 1

---------subsection 1

-------section 2

---------subsection 1

---------subsection 2

---

My original phrasing of this question was as follows:

This is, what I hope to be, a fairly straight forward and simple question. When using `subfiles` can one pool multiple documents with a `book` class? Or, at the very least, separate title pages and accordingly separate TOC?

Comment: You can also do that simply by using `\include` and `\input`. The only thing `subfiles` adds is the possibility to also LaTeX the individual parts separately. If you don't need that, I think just using `\input` and `\include` is easier.

Comment: @PietvanOostrum I am unfamiliar with those commands...

Comment: Please read some elementary LaTeX documentation then. But to give a short answer: `\input{filename}` adds the contents of `filename` as if it was typed there in the document. `\include{filename}` does the same, but also starts a new page before the included text. It does a bit more, but basically that's it.

Comment: @PietvanOostrum so how would that allow me to have two book class documents or at least two titles and corresponding TOCs?

Comment: OK, I think I might have misunderstood your question. Can you formulate your question in such a way that it is understandable? Maybe with an example?

Comment: @PietvanOostrum I have rephrased the question :)

Comment: Maybe the `combine` package is what you need. Only I am not sure if it will work nicely with `scrbook`.

Answer (score 2):

You could try the following with the `combine` package:

Get a copy a `combine.cls` in your working directory (where your combined book document will be), and make the following change in the copy:

After the line:

```
\DeclareOption{book}{\def\c@lclass{book}}
```

insert

```
\DeclareOption{scrbook}{\def\c@lclass{scrbook}}
```

Then use a document like this to combine the books:

```
\documentclass[11pt,scrbook,titlepage]{combine}

\usepackage{xxxxx}% <==== put all the \usepackages you need here.
                  % Add other definitions from the preambles
                  % also here (the book preambles will not be used).

\author{I Myself}
\title{Combined Book}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\newpage
\begin{papers}
  \import{book1}
  \import{book2}
\end{papers}
\end{document}
```

Comment: would this render a title page for the meta document, with a TOC just for the books, and then also provide the separate title page, TOCs, etc for the books?

Comment: Yes, I get a title page for the combined document, then title pages and TOCs for each of the books. By default these are not a separate page each (which means you get the title, the TOC and the first chapter on the same page(s) for each book, but this can be cured by putting extra `\newpage` commands in the original books. The `combine` class is not designed to work with the `koma` classes, so `scrbook` may complain of some changes that `combine` makes. Whether these destroy your book's formatting I don't know. I would say, just try it.

Comment: What if you do not have a local copy of combine. Can those definitions go before document class?

Comment: No, that is impossible. But why can you not make a copy of `combine.cls`?

Comment: It is an online editor....

Comment: But can't you add your own files there? Just download a copy of combine.cls and paste it in your editor.

Answer (score 2):

Only as an addendum to [Piet's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/342814/9057):

Instead of patching class `combine` you can use KOMA-Script package `scrlfile` to replace loading class `book` by loading class `scrbook`.

MWE for this suggestion:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{book1.tex}
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{mwe}

\title{First Book}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\blinddocument
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{book2.tex}
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{mwe}

\title{Second Book}
\maketitle

\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}

\RequirePackage{scrlfile}
\ReplaceClass{book}{scrbook}% load scrbook instead of book
\documentclass[11pt,book,titlepage]{combine}

\usepackage{mwe}% <==== put all the \usepackages you need here.
                  % Add other definitions from the preambles
                  % also here (the book preambles will not be used).

\author{I Myself}
\title{Combined Book}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\cleardoubleoddpage
\begin{papers}
  \import{book1}
  \import{book2}
\end{papers}
\end{document}
```